# Android Ormlite getting SelectorIterator<T, ID> instead of CloseableIterator<T>

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I am trying out android Ormlite but getting this error:

```
com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator cannot be cast to
       com.j256.ormlite.dao.CloseableIterable
```

This is the code causing the error; instead of `CloseableIterator<Employee>` it is returning `SelectorIterator<Employee>`:

```
public CloseableIterator<Employee> getEmployeesToSync(Context context){
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    CloseableIterator<Employee> iterator = null;
    try {
        iterator = databaseHelper.getEmployeesDao().queryBuilder().
            where().
            eq(Employee.IS_SYNCED, false).
            iterator();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return iterator;
}
```

Comment: Casting the result to ```SelectorIterator<T, ID>``` solved the issue; it is bizarre. My method returns ```CloseableIterator<Employee>``` but I have to cast it to ```SelectorIterator<Employee, Integer>. 
            SelectIterator<Employee, Integer> Employees = (SelectIterator<Employee, Integer>) EmployeesProvider.getInstance().getEmployeesToSync(getContext()); ```

Comment: What line is giving that error?  Is it a runtime error?  Can you post the full exception?

Comment: It is a runtime error, and I have posted error (no relevant stacktrace). Btw I just inspected the return type of the ```getEmployeesToSync``` method its type is : SelectorIterator<Employee> instead of ```CloseableIterator<Employee>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator cannot be cast to
>    com.j256.ormlite.dao.CloseableIterable
> ```

I'm not 100% sure why this is happening unless the `Employee` type is a different class.  I'd make sure that your code is referring to the same class by looking at the import statements.

This shouldn't be a casting issue because `SelectIterator<T, ID>` extends `CloseableIterable<T>`, and [`Where.iterator()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#iterator()) returns a `CloseableIterator` which happens to be a `SelectIterator`.  See the [`SelectIterator` javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/SelectIterator.html).

I'm not sure if this is the problem but you *will* need to cast a `CloseableIterator<T>` to be a `SelectIterator<T, ID>` because there is no way for the generics to infer the ID type.  So if you have a 
`CloseableIterator<Employee>` and the id type of `Employee` is an `int` then you will need to case it to be a `SelectIterator<Employee, Integer>`.

Comment: Thanks, I put a code somewhere to help you reproduce the issue.